# Openpxl does not add new entries to File

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I tried to add a new item to an already existing spreadsheet but it doesn't seem to work. However, the file's property matches my timestamp of last recent call in python 3. Because this is a rather larger project, some background information may be necessary for trouble shooting.

- I am using Openpyxl 2.5.3
- As for now, both files (*.py and *.xlsx) are in the same directory
- furthermore, they're currently stored in a OneDrive folder which synchronizes automatically

When trying to run

```
def add_value(self, to_position: Coordinate, new_value: str or int) -> bool:
    try:
        string = get_column_letter(to_position[0]) if isinstance(to_position[0], int) else to_position[0]
        self.Sheet[f"{string}{to_position[1]}"].value = str(new_value)
        workbook.save(self.Fullfilename)
        return True
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError) as e:
        print(f"{e}\n{filename} couldn't be found in current working directory\n[{os.listdir()}].")
        return False
```

the function evaluates to `True` but no changes to the files have been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I *am* really stupid. My `__init__` constructor comes with an attribute called `self.Workbook`. But I misspellt it `self.Worbook`, which in turn affected `self.Sheet = self.WorBook.active`. Note that I wrote `workbook.save(self.Fullfilename)`, but I have to save the changes to `self.Workbook.save(Fullfilename)`. As a final note, the *.xlsx's timestamp update in file properties was displayed next to 更新日時 (date of modification) which initially lead to my confusion whether my script accessed or edited the spreadsheet for real.